# Determine the white point in the image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors

```
RGB = imread('originalimg.png');                                    
MyImrgb = reshape(im2double(RGB), [],3);
Imrgb = MyImrgb.^2.2; %gamma correction
[x, y, z] = size(Imrgb);
                     % ld      % rg      %yv
ldrgyv2rgbMat =  [1,1,0.236748566577269;
                  1,-0.299338211934457,-0.235643322285071;
                  1,0.0137437185685517,1];  % B
MyImrgbCol = reshape(Imrgb * ldrgyv2rgbMat, size(RGB));
MyImldrgyvCol = reshape(reshape(MyImrgbCol, [],3) *inv(ldrgyv2rgbMat),size(MyImrgbCol));
imshow(MyImldrgyvCol)
```

I need to find the white point in the color image in a particular axis say x axis. How do I proceed about it?

In an image, every axis has its own color. The transition point from that color, say for example red to green, the midpoint would be the white point. How do I write a Matlab code to get that point?

Comment: "every axis has its own color" It does? Could you elaborate? Is this some specific type of image you are dealing with?

Comment: Yes, I had a normal RGB image, I changed the color space to DKL. In this DKL color space, I want to look at the color in the x-axis, so my x-axis is the red-green color axis. Now I want to look at the transition point where it moves from red2green. So i would like to create a histogram showing the transition point as the median point and to look at the image with that point. I will attach my code and image.

Comment: The white point won't be at some arbitrary point on an axis, you'll need to examine the image to know where to place it.

Comment: So when you say you're looking along the x-axis, you mean you are looking along the red-green axis of a color histogram. There is no reason why this histogram would show any specific feature (peak or trough) at the white point. You find the white point by identifying something white or gray in the picture, and measuring its color.

Comment: Is there a way for me to examine the white point or the mid-grey level using Matlab. I could not think of code for that.

Comment: @ Cris Luengo sir, could you explain to me with some example? I am stuck in this project for a long time.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, so how can i do that? like img(2,:) == 255 something like this in my code could give me a middle line on the white point in the histogram of the LM axis ?